# How to bridge a string of edges?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to bridge the edges on a string of edges to another string of edges with faces. (See image)

[image: What I'm trying to do]

How can I do this? When I use the `F` key, it does something strange because the height of the edges fluctuates. Also, bridge edge loops tells me to "Select at least two edge loops." What should I do?

Comment: Which edges are related to your question - marked in blue or not ? Could you post screenshot with only edges you're trying to bridge ? If *Bridge Edge Loops* gives that error probably you're trying to fill closed loop and another filling tool will suit you better. But it's hard to tell given this example.

Comment: The selected (blue) edges are what I am trying to bridge between. The selection are *not* loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

- Bridge Edge loops can handle this situation.
- Make a selection on the top row of n contiguous vertices.
- Also make a selection on the bottom row of n contiguous vertices.
- Bridge Edge loops.

Comment: I was able to find my problem thanks to your answer: turned out that my selection was a single loop instead of two separate strands.